# How to solve "Canvas is tainted by cross-origin data"

Tags: javascript, face-detection

I am using the face_detection library or API from this tutorial on youtube
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FfHilvUc25c 
I have tried the same thing but I am getting the error that canvas has been  tainted by cross origin data. There is no canvas in my index.html.

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.facedetection.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#picture').faceDetection({
                complete: function (faces) {
                    console.log(faces);
                }
            });
        })
    </script>

  <img id="picture" src="img/face1.jpg">
```

I was expecting to get an array in console but nothing is printed exceptan error which says "Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data."

Comment: Are you running this on a local server? As a file in HTML? This makes a difference. If you are using just a file you opened from the Finder or Explorer, it _will_ fail as any file served from your OS is off-limits and will taint the canvas used for face detection here. The library needs to read image data, but if the origin ia unknown or unsafe, your canvas will be tainted and no longer usable. Many modern features (like using the local camera) is also only available when served from a web-server, for your safety.

Comment: Since this is a normal HTML file I an running by opening in chrome. And the I am providing the images from the same folder

Comment: Yes that won't work, you will need to spin up a local server or the browser will consider it a cross-origin request and the canvas will be tainted. The `file://` protocol treats every file as it's own server - this is to avoid a malicious hacker sending an HTML file that then scours the content of your hard drive when you double click it. If you are unfamiliar, a decent way to run a local server when you start is using a application like MAMP and then pointing it at your folder.

Comment: Yes it works now when I used local server. Thanks

Comment: The answer you provided is working fine. Can you post that as an answer instead of comment so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you load in textures or images to use on a canvas, its source needs to be trusted and safe to prevent any misuse of the internals of a canvas. In order to accomplish this, you need to serve your files from the same domain or ensure that the other server communicates its intentions properly with a CORS header. If you try to draw an image from an insecure source, the canvas will be tainted and no image data can be read from it anymore.

You can use a local server (like MAMP if you need a GUI, otherwise a browsersync server in node will do just fine) to be able to access and manipulate files hosted on the same server. There is more to this, but check out the MDN docs on this phenomenon: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image